# Nginx chrome ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when not trying to use ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've set-up Nginx both default and a config in sites-enabled and yet I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when trying to connect. I never configured anything to use ssl and trying to connect with http results in a redirect to https. Firefox shows a SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG error.

Maybe related is that I'm trying to set up a Strapi (NodeJS) server which gives me the same error when launched on the server. I thought that Nginx would maybe fix it but even in it's basic configuration I get the same error.

If anyone could that with this that would be greatly appreciated, feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Please provide all relevant configuration.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider What would you understand under relevant configuration? Everything is left on default on a fresh install of Debian 10.

Comment: I just reinstalled the server as Rocky Linux 8 and it seems to be working, since it was happening before on Ubuntu as well it seems to be a Debian thing